# How can i get around this?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have this piece of code and i dont understand why I m getting the following error:

```
local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final
```

Here is my code

```
    public int firstMissingPositive(int[] nums) {

        int k;

        for (int i = 1;; i++) {
            if (!Arrays.stream(nums).anyMatch(x -> x != i)) {
                k = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return k;
    }
```

Comment: If you typed *local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final* or some combination of it, SO would have shown you several duplicates.

Comment: The code has very bad performance (_O(n^2)_). You can get better performance by either sorting the array, or by building a `boolean[]` of found values, or ...

Comment: For the future: please spend some time to find a *reasonable* title for your question. This is a Q/A community, all content should be written to be helpful for future readers. Few future readers will find *How can i get around this?* to be a helpful starting point ...

Comment: Sorry for that today. I will keep that in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `i` is not *effectively final* (see `i++`), and it must be to be used in a lambda expression.

It is easy enough to fix, by assigning to a new local variable inside the loop:

```
public int firstMissingPositive(int[] nums) {
    int k;
    for (int i = 1;; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        if (! Arrays.stream(nums).anyMatch(x -> x != j)) {
            k = j;
            break;
        }
    }
    return k;
}
```

Comment: this should also work without final keyword for `j` right?

Comment: @Deadpool Yes. It's "effectively final" even without the keyword.

Comment: sounds good @Michael